# rxjs switchMap need to return subscribed observable

Tags: rxjs, observable

Here here the requirement:

When click start button, emit event x times every 100ms, each emit correspond an UI update. When x times emit complete, it will trigger a final UI update, look simple right?

Here is my code:

```
const start$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('start'), 'click')
const intervel$ = interval(100)
    .pipe(
        take(x),
        share()
    )
var startLight$ = start$
    .pipe(
        switchMap(() => {
            intervel$
                .pipe(last())
                .subscribe(() => {
                    // Update UI
                })
            return intervel$
        }),
        share()
    )
startLight$
    .subscribe(function (e) {
        //Update UI
    })
```

Obviously, subscribe inside `switchMap` is anti-pattern, so I tried to refactor my code:

```
const startInterval$ = start$
    .pipe(
        switchMapTo(intervel$),
    )
startInterval$.pipe(last())
    .subscribe(() => {
        //NEVER Receive value
    })

const startLight$ = startInterval$.pipe(share())
```

The problem is that intervel$ stream is generated inside `switchMap` and can not be accessed outside, you can only access the stream who generate interval$, i.e. start$ which never complete!

Is there is smarter way to handle such kind of problem or it was an inherent limitation of `rxjs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close.  Use last() inside intervel$ to only emit the final one to the subscribe below.  Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-q-54339645?file=index.ts).  Here are details from the StackBlitz:

```
const start$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('start'), 'click');
const intervel$ = interval(100)
    .pipe(
        tap(() => console.log('update UI')), // Update UI here
        take(x),
        last()
    );

const startInterval$ = start$
    .pipe( switchMapTo(intervel$));

startInterval$
    .subscribe(() => {
        console.log('will run once');
    });
```

## Update

If you do not wish to use `tap()`, then you can simply cause start$ to finish by taking only the first emission and then completing with either `take(1)` or `first()`.  [Here is a new StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-q-54339645-update?file=index.ts) showing this.

```
const start$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('start'), 'click')
    .pipe(
      first()
    );
const intervel$ = interval(100)
    .pipe( 
      take(x) 
    );

const startInterval$ = start$
    .pipe( 
      switchMapTo(intervel$)
    );

startInterval$
    .subscribe(
      () => console.log('Update UI'),
      err => console.log('Error ', err),
      () => console.log('Run once at the end')
    );
```

The downside to this approach (or any approach that completes the Observable) is that once completed it won't be reused.  So for example, clicking multiple times on the button in the new StackBlitz won't work.  Which approach to use (the first one that can be clicked over and over or the one that completes) depends on the results you need.

## Yet Another Option

Create two `intervel$` observables, one for the intermediate UI updates and one for the final one.  Merge them together and only do the UI updating in the subscribe.  [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-q-54339645-update2?file=index.ts) for this option

code:

```
const start$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('start'), 'click')
const intervel1$ = interval(100)
    .pipe( 
      take(x)
    );
const intervel2$ = interval(100)
    .pipe(
      take(x+1),
      last(),
      mapTo('Final')
    );

const startInterval$ = start$
    .pipe( 
      switchMapTo(merge(intervel1$, intervel2$))
    );

startInterval$
    .subscribe(
        val => console.log('Update UI: ', val)
    );
```

## A more idiomatic way, same logic as previous one (By Guichi)

```
import { switchMapTo, tap, take, last, share, mapTo } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { fromEvent, interval, merge } from 'rxjs';

const x = 5;

const start$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('start'), 'click');


const intervel$ = interval(100);

const intervel1$ = intervel$
  .pipe(
    take(x)
  );
const intervel2$ = intervel1$
  .pipe(
    last(),
    mapTo('Final')
  );

const startInterval$ = start$
  .pipe(
    switchMapTo(merge(intervel1$, intervel2$))
  );

startInterval$
  .subscribe(
    val => console.log('Update UI: ', val)
  );
```

## Reflection

The key problem of the original question is to 'use the same observable in different ways', i.e. during the progress and the final. So `merge` is an pretty decent logic pattern to target this kind of problem

Comment: @Fan Cheung thanks both your guys, you basically provide the save solution! They are definitely helpful. However someone think 'move important side effects from do to subscribe'[https://egghead.io/lessons/rxjs-move-important-side-effects-from-do-to-subscribe], Is this a decent recommendation or any way to achieve?

Comment: Also, I suppose `subject` can solve this problem somehow. But `subject` feel unfamiliar to me. Just a vague idea it may work. Is it possible to flesh out ?

Comment: I seldomly put anything in subscribe(), because stream suppose to be reusable, composable. Most of the time you need to improve and refactor fragments of streams a lot while you developing features,, if you want extra logic, just chain and extend the stream and save it as another stream.

Comment: @Guichi - I added an update above with an alternative solution where the Observable completes.

Comment: The updated solution is different from the previous one which is needed, it emit only ONCE and the whole stream terminate

Comment: Yes, that is the downside to completing an Observable, as I mentioned.  Ok, last idea from me is as follows: create two intervel's - one for the intermediate UI updates and one for the final one.  Merge them together and Update the UI in the subscribe only, no taps: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-q-54339645-update2?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Put your update logic inside the `switchMap` and `tap()` , tap will run multiple time and only last emission will be taken by subscribe()

```
const startInterval$ = start$
    .pipe(
        switchMap(()=>intervel$.pipe(tap(()=>//update UI),last()),
    )
startInterval$
    .subscribe(() => {
//    will run one time
    })
```